# How to change values in a list of lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to change the values in a list of lists. I wrote this for loop as if I am working with a list. I do not know how to apply it to a list of lists. Any recommendations?

```py
a = [[1, 0], [0 ,0]]
for n, i in enumerate(a):
  if i == 1:
    a[n] = 0
  elif i == 0:
    a[n] = 1

print(a)
```

Comment: `a[n][i] = 0`, I suppose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you need the index of both the nested lists AND the integers within those lists, you would need to use the **enumerate()** function for both like so:

```
a = [[1, 0], [0, 0]]

for index1, sublist in enumerate(a):
  for index2, number in enumerate(sublist):
    if number == 1:
      a[index1][index2] = 0
    elif number == 0:
      a[index1][index2] = 1

print(a)
```

Using your variable names, it can be written as:

```
for n, i in enumerate(a):
  for k, j in enumerate(i):
    if j == 1:
      a[n][k] = 0
    elif j == 0:
      a[n][k] = 1
```

Output:

```
[[0, 1], [1, 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your n is int and i is list in this case. You could check this snippet and make it parameterized as per your need.

```
a= [[1, 0], [0 ,0]]
for n, i in enumerate(a):
  for j in range(0,len(i)):
    if j == 1:
      a[n][j] = 0
    elif j == 0:
      a[n][j] = 1

print(a)
```